# Cron job not running on Godaddy

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I've always used mysql events for scheduled tasks but my hosting doesn't allow the event scheduler to run. I've had to make the switch to cron jobs and I think I'm very close to getting them working. Spent hours reading tutorials and testing but no luck.

I have a cron job that I want to run every minute, here's what it runs:

```
/web/cgi-bin/php5 /public_html/velrania.com/cron.php > /dev/null 2>&1
```

The php file location is fine, the dev/null part is there to prevent email notifications (unless I've been misinformed) so I think it is the first part which executes php

I've tried changing the path to "/usr/local/bin/php -q" as directed by https://support.godaddy.com/help/article/3483/what-is-a-cron-job?countrysite=uk but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ha, I'm stupid.

```
/public_html/velrania.com/cron.php
```

needed to be

```
/home/USERNAME/public_html/velrania.com/cron.php
```

Comment: If you have SSH set up, a good way to test you got the right url is to run the command in terminal yourself.

Comment: @Ryan Mckenna I have also same problem.I need to javascript file in godaddy.my command is    /home/myname/public_html/myjavascriptclass.js